# Is it safe to use a bare drive in a 2.5" metal enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, external-hard-drive, enclosures

I just recently replaced my Seagate Momentus 7200.4 with a Samsung Pro 512GB SSD. I wanted to continue using the Seagate Momentus (as a way to access old files should I need to), so I bought a Sabrent 2.5" enclosure. The enclosure is milled aluminum as far as I can tell.

I didn't consider, however, that the Seagate would be bare on the bottom. In the laptop it was resting on some sort of black anti-electric plastic, but the enclosure has no such thing. Will there be enough clearance to avoid shorting out the electronics on the underside of the drive? Is there something I can place inside the enclosure to mimic the anti-electric plastic inside the laptop?

Comment: Its safe to assume that Sabrent, a company that sells millions of products, and like millions of the very enclosure you purchased has product engineers that designed a product where your concern is unwarranted.  In other words, Sabrent wouldn't sell products, if it shorted out consumers HDDs.

Comment: You could cut a piece of thin plastic or thin card stock and make your own insulator.

Comment: Moab that's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine - By observation,  the bottom mounting holes on most 2.5mm drives are something like 1mm or so above the circuit board and it shouldn't make any contact with the base, assuming its reasonably flat.